# Configure eth0 ip address,subnetmask, gateway using bash script

Tags: linux, networking, centos

i need to update /etc/sysconfig/network-script/eth0 using bash
when i tried to update it, i find no changes

I'm looking for a bash script to configure eth0 ip address,subnetmask, gateway using bash script ...

How can i do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just use the ifconfig and route commands

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.2.123 netmask 255.255.255.0
route add default gw 192.168.2.1
```